# My Picture is not showing up in android studio which is causing the app to crash

Tags: java, android

Hi I have a image which refuses to load in a android app and is causing the whole app to crash. The resolution of the image is 3840 by 2160 (4K) if that helps.

Comment: Any questions? Any logcat? Any exception? Any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) to load an image. It has multiple useful features as well.